# How to stop non-digit input causing my Python program to crash?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program for a class that will have a conversation. I want to force the user to input an int for the variables `your_age` and `my_age`. I've done a lot of research and this I've tried to code the program the way I believe I'm being told but it's not running if I put 'one' instead of '1'. If the user inputs 'one' I want them to get an error code and have the opportunity to re-enter the variable.

Code:

```
name = input('Salutations what is your name?') #user will input their name and it will be saved in the variable name
print('That is a nice name ' + name + ' whats your favorite color') #genorate a sentance using the variable name

color =input('') #this input is collecting the information from the above sentence
print (color + ' is a great color')#make user feel like they picked a good color

#your_age = int(input('How old are you?'))#user sets variable age
while True:
    your_age = int(input('How old are you?'))
    try:
        your_age = int(your_age)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('INVALID: you can round up or down but please enter your age using digits')


my_age = int(input(' how old am I?'))

combine_age = str(your_age + my_age)
print ('Our combined age is ')
print (combine_age)
```

I had the code running but I was stress testing and figured out that if I didn't put in a digit the program would crash. I researched on YouTube and in Automating the Boring Stuff and couldn't find a sufficient answer.

Comment: What is the exact error you are facing ? What is the stacktrace ?

Comment: Remove the int conversion from this line: `your_age = int(input('How old are you?'))`. It should be just `your_age = input('How old are you?')`

Comment: Can you provide exmaple(s) of "didnt put in a diget"?

Comment: Also, you need to do similar error handling for `my_age`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert input into integer inside of Try block and implement error handling for both variables. **your_age** and **my_age**.

```
name = input('Salutations what is your name?') #user will input their name and it will be saved in the variable name
print('That is a nice name ' + name + ' whats your favorite color') #genorate a sentance using the variable name

color =input('Your favorite color?') #this input is collecting the information from the above sentence
print (color + ' is a great color')#make user feel like they picked a good color

while True:
    try:
        your_age = int(input('How old are you?'))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('INVALID: you can round up or down but please enter your age using digits only')

while True:
    try:
        my_age = int(input('How old am I?'))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('INVALID: you can round up or down but please enter your age using digits only')

combine_age = str(your_age + my_age)
print ('Our combined age is '+combine_age)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write a general purpose function to acquire integer input from the user.

Something like this:

```
def get_int(prompt: str) -> int:
    while True:
        s = input(prompt)
        try:
            return int(s)
        except ValueError:
            print('\aInvalid - try again')

print(get_int('Hello: '))
```

Thus, wherever you need an int, just call get_int() with an appropriate prompt and you can be assured that you'll only ever get a valid int returned